Getting error on update: Blocked executable in the ESP, ensure grub and shim are up to date:
When I update my system, Kubuntu 23.10 x86_64, I get the error message:
Blocked executable in the ESP, ensure grub and shim are up to date: /media/root/3841-B9E0/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi Authenticode checksum [af79b14064601bc0987d4747af1e914a228c05d622ceda03b7a4f67014fee767] is present in dbx
Called up a list of bootups:
efibootmgr -v
I did not see the errored path in the list of available bootups, so I did:
sudo rm /media/root/3841-B9E0/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi
..and I got the following error:
rm: cannot remove '/media/root/3841-B9E0/EFI/debian/shimx64.efi': No such file or directory
What might be the problem with my attempted fix to the 'Blocked executable' error?

I have no idea why this was not answered and was even down-voted!

I find odd the path /media/root/3841-B9E0/EFI/, it should normally be /boot/efi/EFI/. Anyway, in my case not just that file but all those in my folder were old, so I removed the whole directory /boot/efi/EFI/custom. But I followed this procedure, which is meant for purging EFI of old unused OS entries (each bullet is a separate line):
• sudo su
• cd /boot/efi/EFI
• ls, and then selecting my folder :
• rm -rf custom. After that, the update of that UEFI dbx package worked in Discover.
